# Email massge with .xlx format from python has .dat type in outlook

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a problem. I want to send excel file with Russian words (like a привет.xlx) to outlook post.
below, i write a code for test. After @att.add_header@ my russian text, has another text with bad text (like a utf-8''%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82) and my message in outlook is @.dat@

```
filename = 'тест'
att.add_header('Content-Disposition','attachment',filename=filename)
print(att)
msg.attach(att)
```

result:

```
Content-Type: application/xlsx
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename*=utf-8''%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82
```

please, help me!

Comment: Does the file really have to have a russian name?

Comment: thx for comment, Yeah, it is very important!!! Because, if i use english name - it is OK.

Comment: Do you have solve for my problem?

Comment: No, unfortunately I don't know how to solve this. I think you misunderstood my question. Why don't you use a filename that doesn't contain non ASCII characters?

Comment: Thx, I think, I understood your question. I want to use utf-8, because russian filename it is very important for my customer. like 'ПРИ_ВЕТ_29.01.xlx'

Comment: What library are you using to send the file? Have you tried searching on the internet for how to use non-utf8 characters in file names?

Answer (score -1):

I use code as below and it could solve my problem, for your reference.

```py
from email import encoders
from email.header import Header

part.add_header(
                "Content-Disposition",
                "attachment; filename= %s" % Header(attachment_paths[att]).encode('utf-8')
            )
```

Comment: The filename is already UTF-8.

Comment: I know it UTF-8 already. I try  'ПРИ_ВЕТ_29.01.xlsx' with my code and it works for me.